# Event Tracking in Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I'm using Universal Analytics tracking code and would like to start tracking click events for one of the buttons. I added the `ga('send'...)` on click event via jQuery. Do I need to make any changes to the actual Universal Analytics tracking snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to make any changes. I'm assuming you are invoking the library and creating the tracker through the standard method.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<button onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'your_category', 'your_action', 'your_label');">
```

With jQuery, placing an event listener on the button:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    console.log("sending your event"); // use this to debug
    ga('send', 'event', 'your_category', 'your_action', 'your_label');
}
```

Comment: Any updates, OP?

Comment: Above will work, just make sure before you redirect that the above event finishes else you will have some missing clicks.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. [Google mentions that the events tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#gc-wrapper) is part of analytics.js (which is what the default Universal Analytics snippet is calling).

I'm sure you already saw this, but in case you didn't and you're wanting to confirm that you did the jQuery part correctly, [here's Google's example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#usingjquery).